# Returning two integers with loops?

Tags: java, loops, integer

I'm a beginner doing a loop tutorial, and I've been given the below task

"A battleship board is a 2-dimensional grid with coordinates like (0,0), (0,1), (0,2), etc.

Create a method called PrintCoordinates(int x, int y),where x and y define the size of the board.  Print all the possible coordinates in the board. Hint: loops can contain loops"

DESIRED OUTPUT (9, 9):

- (0, 0)
- (0, 1)
- (0, 2)
- (0, 3)
- ...
- (0, 9)
- (1, 0)
- (1, 2)
- (1, 3)
- ...
- (9, 9)

My code is below

```
public class Ex3_PrintGrid {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int grid = printcoordinates(4, 7);
    System.out.println(grid);

    }

public static int printcoordinates(int x, int y){
    int n = 0;
    while ( n < x){
        int m = 0;
        while (m < y){
        m = m + 1;
        return m;
        }

    n = n + 1;
    }
    return n;

}
```

My rationale is to achieve the below steps

1) Get y coordinate value to increase by 1 until it is equal to the declared value in the method

2) In the meantime, the x value waits for the y value to increase before it increases on its own by one

3) The whole thing loops again with the new (x+1) value.

Problem is I'm very confused on how I can do a loop within a loop that returns 2 integers within a single method?

Do let me know if my question isn't clear

UPDATE:

I made a change to code based on the tips below and still got an error at the System.out.println line. Does anyone know what is wrong?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    printcoordinates (4, 5);    
    }

public static int printcoordinates(int x, int y){
    int n = 0;
    int m = 0;
    while ( n < x){
        while (m < y){
        m = m + 1;
        }

    n = n + 1;
    }
    System.out.println( n, m);  
}
```

Comment: this makes no sense your method is called `printcoordinates` and does not actually `print` anything. your variable is called `grid` but is a single `int`? Java `Class` names are `UpperCamelCase`, `method` names are `lowerCamelCase`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the hints that should get you started:

- `printcoordinates` should return nothing, i.e. be `void`
- Returning from the middle of a method terminates the method immediately. You will not jump back into your loop, even when you call the method again
- Printing in a loop does not terminate a loop, so you can print pairs in the inner of the two loops (i.e. where you currently return `m`, print a pair `m, n`; put parentheses around the pair.).

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I modified the code based on your tips to make something like what I updated above. It can't work though... do you know what is wrong? :/

Comment: @KennethYong That's because `System.out.println( n, m); ` needs to be inside the second `while` loop, i.e. right on the line before `m = m + 1;`.

Comment: hmm I tried that and I still got this error on the println 

"The method println(int) in the type PrintStream is not applicable for the arguments (int, int)"

Comment: @KennethYong It should be `System.out.println("("+n+", "+m+")");`

Comment: Ok done! Umm now I see an error at `public static int printcoordinates(int x, int y)`

It says as a quick fix I should add either add a return statement, or change the method type to void? I think this is because we made the output a string instead of an integer?

Thanks so much for spending time on this :)

Comment: @KennethYong That's the point 1 from my answer: the return type of the method needs to be `void`.

Comment: would have wanted to move this to chat but I don't have enough reputation it seems :/

I can get the code to run now :) The thing is the loop stops when the condition for m has been met, but does not carry on when the condition for n is not yet met.

I.e: Doing printcoordinates (4,2) would only print (0,1) and (0,2) but does not continue to give me (1,1) and (1,2)?

Comment: @KennethYong You need to move `int m = 0;` declaration inside the first `while` loop, so that `m` gets reset each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Java is single return. You can only return as single primitive or Object from a method.

If you want to return 2 values at once, which it is not clear what you actually want to do. You need to define an Object to hold this data such as.

```
public class Coordinate
{
    public final int x;
    public final int y;

    public Coordinate(final int x, final int y) { this.x = x; this.y = y; }
}
```

Change your method signature to be `public static Coordinate findCoordinate(final int x, final int y)`

Create a new one of these with `final Coordinate c = new Coordinate(x,y);` and return it with `return c;`

Answer (score 1):

To return your coordinate pair, you should probably start by defining a class `Coord` like

```
class Coord {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Coord(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("(%d, %d)", x, y);
    }
}
```

Then your method should be to get a `List` of `Coord` instances. Something like,

```
public static List<Coord> getCoordinates(int x, int y) {
    List<Coord> al = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
            al.add(new Coord(i, j));
        }
    }
    return al;
}
```

Finally, you can call it in `main` like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Coord> grid = getCoordinates(4, 7);
    System.out.println(grid);
}
```

Output is (formatted for post)

```
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (0, 5), (0, 6), (1, 0), (1, 1),
 (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3),
 (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5),
 (3, 6)]
```